# XCode - Workspaces

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, workspace

i'm developing a framework and i would like to know if there is a method for share the code across multiple project. Example : i have my workspace with my framework project and a test application project for the fw; then, i have another project of an app and i need to use the framework, but i want to link the framework so that when i modify the original code in workspace even the code in the project is updated without import every time the .framework file.
Is it possible?
If not, how can i do to share code across projects?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can easily be done by importing files from the other project. You could create a group called external, right click and choose "add files". Make sure the option "copy items into destination group`s folder" is unchecked.

If  you now change the files in the other project, the changes will be reflected in the dependent one.

Comment: 2 question : the first, when i build the archive it contains even the framework, right? What is the difference between copy items reference items? And the second, if i can reference framework and libraries, what workspaces do?

Comment: First, Yes, your archived project wil contain everything included.
Second, In the case I explained, you reference code across projects. Typically if you want to reuse code from another project.

Comment: Ok, now i have workspace with framework project and test app project. In the test app i want to add framework reference, how can i do? It is like two different project, right? If yes, i add framework without the "copy items..." checked but my headers don't appears and my test app doesn't build.

Comment: I solve the headers problems. But there is a method to import an entire workspace to a project?